# SQL Command Won't fetch any data SSIS

Tags: ssis

I have a problem with one of my SSIS packages called Daily.dtsx, inside Daily.dtsx I have 1 data flow task, inside data flow task have 4 OLE DB Source, other transformation, and Destination, 2 OLE DB Source with data access mode  SQL command from variable, and 2 OLE DB Source with data access mode from SQL Command, but when I run the task, OLE DB source that has data access mode  SQL command from variable won't fetch any data. Why 2 OLE DB Source with data access mode SQL command from variable won't fetch any data?

Comment: _won't fetch any data_ have you checked the SQL query to confirm that it actually returns data?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid yes, I already try to run the query, it fetches thousand of data

Comment: Are you absolutely certain that you are running the SQL that is generated by the variable? That is almost always the issue - you're not running the query that you think you are.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid yes, for the testing purpose, I change data access mode from 'SQL command from variable' to 'SQL Command' that has the same query, I try to run and it works, it fetches thousands of data.